# determine a filesize while downloading

Tags: objective-c, download, asihttprequest, nsfilemanager

I want to determine the fileSize of a file that is downloading.
I work with ASIHTTPRequest and normally it should jump into didReceiveBytes but it doesn't so instead I start a timer that repeatedly checks the filesize at the location.
like this :

```
NSError* error;
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary* itemAttributes = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:_location error:&error];
if(!error){
    unsigned long long fsize = [itemAttributes fileSize];
    [downloadLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu MB downloaded",fsize] ];
    NSLog(@"MB downloaded: %llu", fsize);
} else {
    NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
}
```

the problem is that until the file is finished with the download I get the following Error:

```
  error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed.             (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0xf57aa60 {NSFilePath= "long filename", NSUnderlyingError=0xf57ad90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"
```

after it's finished it finally gives me:

MB downloaded: 34443951

The fact, that I get in the MB downloaded in the end tells me the filepath is right. But why does it tell me that the file doesn't exist while it's downloading? and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Using [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) lib for network, you can do it easily.

Read "**Custom progress tracking**" section.

Or you can use

```
-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
}

long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
```

but there are a lot of solutions in so site:
http://goo.gl/0hrK2

Comment: The problem is that the content-length of the downloading file isn't given when the download starts since it is a stream. I already tried it with a progressDelegate, like said doesn't jump into didReceiveBytes

Comment: You need to doublecheck the server side. It is possible that the server doesn't put that header in the response.

Comment: After asking the people who work on the serverside I got the answer that the server can't send the content-length in the header cause the file is put together while downloading and that it can't be changed. So the only way really, seems to be asking for the filesize through the NSFileManager. I just don't understand what causes the no such file error while downloading

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up asking for the Bytes directly from the ASIHTTP Request with :

```
unsigned long long bytes = request.totalBytesRead;
double mb;
if(bytes >0){
    mb = bytes/1000000.0f;        
    [downloadLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f MB downloaded",mb] ];
}
```

This value is continuously retrieved with the fired timer to update the downloaded Bytes and transformed to represent MB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,it may help you

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [request contentLength];
    [downloadButtton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [downloadButtton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelDownloading) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    long length = [request contentLength];

    fileLength = length;

    NSLog(@"fileLength ====> %f",fileLength);


  //  progressView.hidden=NO;
   // progressText.hidden=NO;
    double length2 = [data length];
    currentLength += length2;
    //    double progress = currentLength/fileLength;



  NSString *firstDataLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f MB",fileLength/1024/1024 ];
   NSString *totalMBytes=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" of %.2f MB",fileLength/1024/1024 ];
   NSString *totalMBytesWritten=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f MB",currentLength/1024/1024];


    NSLog(@"firstDataLength %@",firstDataLength);
    NSLog(@"totalMBytes %@",totalMBytes);
    NSLog(@"totalMBytesWritten %@",totalMBytesWritten);



    progressText.text=[totalMBytesWritten stringByAppendingString:totalMBytes];
    NSUInteger left = [data length];
    NSUInteger nwr = 0;
    do {
        nwr = [fileStreem write:[data bytes] maxLength:left];
        if (-1 == nwr) break;
        left -= nwr;
    } while (left > 0);
    if (left) {
        NSLog(@"stream error: %@", [fileStreem streamError]);
    }


}
```